# Conflict between GroovyTruth and implicit constructor

Tags: groovy, implicit-conversion, specifications

I have noticed some conflict between implicit constructor and GroovyTruth.

Consider following code

```
assert new File('/') == ['/'] as File
assert Boolean.TRUE == ["false"] as Boolean
```

First line is implict call of File(String) constructor.
Second line simply returns **true**, because list is not empty. But it can(should?) call Boolean(String) constructor with different result value(**false**).

Is it bug, documented feature or smth. else? Should I report it as bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
['false'] as Boolean
```

It ends up going through [`DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation.java#L191), which [calls `castToBoolean`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation.java#L247) which [as you can see](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation.java#L159) checks for `null`, then calls `asBoolean` on the `Collection` type which [just checks it's not empty](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L7753)

With the `File` example, it falls through to the bottom of `castToType` and just tries to invoke the [constructor with the contents of the list](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation.java#L342)

I wouldn't say this is a bug, but it's definitely an idiosyncrasy of Groovy that has to be taken in to account (and changing it now would be a massive break with compatibility)

Comment: Thanks to source link! I can understand, what is going there, but source is the best confirmation. It's very interesting, I merely forgot, that Groovy core is opensource!
Question was about existence of two practically identical code lines with drastically different behaviour. If I see documentation page about it, I'll point it there.

Comment: Remember though `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation` is a Codehaus Groovy implementation file, not part of the Groovy Language, so other implementations of Groovy could treat such "idiosyncrasies" differently, like treating them as bugs.

Comment: Luckily there are currently no other implementations of Groovy, and any implementation worth its salt would need to follow the rules for Groovy Truth (which is what this gets caught up in). So this is a bit of a void argument